# Использование <experimental/filesystem> WINDOWS

Tags: c++

Добрый день!

```
 TEMPLATE = app

 CONFIG += console c++1z stl
 CONFIG -= app_bundle
 CONFIG -= qt
 LIBS += -lstdc++fs -lpthread


  SOURCES += \
    main.cpp




#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

namespace example_a
{
void example()
{
auto cur_p = fs::current_path();

cout << cur_p << endl;
cout << fs::current_path().root_path() << endl;
// auto space = fs::space(fs::current_path().root_path());
//cout << fs::current_path().root_directory() << endl;
fs::path p(fs::current_path().root_name());
fs::space_info sp = fs::space(p);

 std::uintmax_t cap = sp.capacity;
 cout << "Total:" << '\t' << cap << "Gb" << endl;
 // cout << "Free :" << '\t' << space.free  << "Gb" << endl;
 // cout << "Avail:" << '\t' << space.available  << "Gb" << endl;
 // std::cin.get();


 }


 }

 int main()
 {
   example_a::example();

 }



"C:\\Users\\<name user>\\Documents\\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_32_bit-Debug"
"C:\\"
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 
'std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot get free space: Unknown error [C:]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как пользоваться таким функционалом под Windows 10, пример запускаю на QT.
Под cygwin работает, но там Cmake, и результаты путей тянутся с эмулированой машины где корень /.

Вот код с той же машины не кути:

```
введите сюда код

#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem::v1;

namespace example_a {
void example() {
    auto cur_p = fs::current_path();

    cout << cur_p << endl;

    auto space = fs::space(fs::current_path().root_path());


    cout << fs::current_path().root_directory() << endl;
    cout << "Total:" << '\t' << space.capacity / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 << "Gb" << endl;
    cout << "Free :" << '\t' << space.free / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 << "Gb" << endl;
    cout << "Avail:" << '\t' << space.available / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 << "Gb" << endl;
    std::cin.get();
    }

   }

 int main()
 {
   example_a::example();

 }



  "/cygdrive/c/Users/<пользователь>i/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug"
   "/"
  Total:    525Gb
  Free :    365Gb
  Avail:    365Gb


  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

  project( untitled2 CXX )

  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

  set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fexceptions")
  find_library(FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY filesystem)
  add_executable(untitled2 main.cpp)

  set( SOURCE_LIB main.cpp )

  set ( CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON )

  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} stdc++fs)
```

Хочу разобраться с ошибкой которую выводит в первом случае QT.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно работать с этим функционалом в Windows 10 под QT? Если конкретнее методом space и space_info, так как в первом примере выводит ошибку. Всю информацию указал какую имею.

Comment: вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Да извините дополнил текст pro файла и вопросом.

Comment: Что у ваз за компилятор? Можете показать вывод `g++ --version`? У меня стоит mingw/gcc 9.2 (поставил из msys2), и тут `<filesystem>` работает нормально (даже без `experimental` и без `-lstdc++fs`).

Comment: `C:\Qt\5.14.1\mingw73_32>g++ --version
g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: @niciegusha Думаю проще всего поставить новый компилятор (msys2 в помощь).

Comment: Спасибо буду разбираться!